# Testing if a function returns a list or a bool

Tags: python

I have a function that return either a **list** or **False**, what is the most *elegant* way to test if the function returns a list in an if statement ( or else if it returns False ). I'm testing the "type" of the value returned but it feels clumsy , surely there is a better way to test if the function returns False ( or a list ) .

thank you

Comment: Is the list it returns ever empty?

Comment: nope, it's never empty

Comment: Is it pythonic to have different return types of a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably make more sense to return a `list` or `None` here:

```
result == my_func()
if result is None:
    foo()
else:
    bar(result)
```

---

Actually, since you never return an empty list, use that as your exceptional return value - think of the function as "get me all the things which are..." - if there are none, the answer is a list of 0 items, not `False`:

```
result = my_func()
if result:
    use_list(result)
else:
    empty_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list returns is guaranteed not to be empty, then simply using `if result` will do it.

Using `if lst` is the standard way of checking if a list is non-empty, as empty lists evaluate to `False` in a boolean context. Because your function only ever returns non-empty lists or `False`, this will work.

This can become confusing however, and it would make much more sense returning an empty list rather than `False` (although this is depending on the context).

Answer (score 1):

```
result = function()
if result:
    do_whatever()
```

Nonempty lists are considered true in a boolean context, so if your function never returns an empty list, you can just use `if result`. However, why is your function returning `False` at all? Consider whether returning an empty list would make more sense. If it wouldn't be appropriate to use an empty list, `None` is still probably better suited for the task than `False`.

Answer (score 0):

If possible in your case, you should change the function to return an empty list instead of `False` (or to raise an exception), which would be a better interface.

Otherwise, I would do:

```
res = foo()
if res is False:
   ...
else:
   for item in res: ...
```

If the list returned is guaranteed not to be empty, it would be slightly more elegant to use `if not res` instead of `if res is False`.

Comment: Pretty sure you ahould not use `is` to compare booleans

Comment: @Eric, I'm pretty sure you can. [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) say about class `bool`: "Its only instances are False and True"

Comment: @shx2 But it is not very pythonic. It is better to rely on boolean behaviour of the objects you deal with, and that works with `if not res:`, as you describe at the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Under your described circumstances, you as well can work with

```
result = my_func() or []
```

because:

- `my_func()` returns a non-empty list under "normal" circumstances and
- returns `False` otherwise.
- `or` yields the first operand if it is true, as all non-empty lists are, so it just leaces the result value.
- `or` yields the second operand if the first one is false.

So now, `result` is either a non-empty list or an empty one.

If you are going to iterate over the list now. just do so:

```
for item in result:
    do_something_with(item)
```

If `result` is an empty list, the `for` loop will just be skipped so that no further `if` check will be necessary, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** use isinstance

```
result = func()
if isinstance(result, list):
  True
else:
  False
```

or

```
from collections import Sequence
result = func()
if isinstance(result, Sequence)
   True
else:
   False
```